# C# Windows Service not applying code changes

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

I have a windows service with an installer created (with InstallShield), but now I want to make some changes.
The changes in the main class of the project are not applying when I compile and run the service, but the changes in other classes work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it should not happen, Also do not try to write any business logic in the main class of the Windows Service. Always add into OnStart() method and Call the same in Main Method of the Service. Also, for live debugging you can put logs creation code in the service which will let you know where the code got failed once you installed after creating Setup from InstallShield.

Comment: A week ago, I was able to change the code and the changes were applied, I had a timer and now I added a second timer. I use NLog putting a string into a log message when the service starts, and now I change that message but the message doesn't update in log file.

Comment: Are you sure that your service is starting after installation..If yes, you must be getting the logs of the Main method else , its not starting ..

Comment: More info: I have a Setup InstallShield, but I've the service installed in my computer with installUtil.

Answer (score 0):

You should stop the service from Services window first. Then change the .dll file as you want. Then start again.

This link will be a lifesaver on this, because I was experiencing the very same thing few years earlier:

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx
```

Comment: I'm stopping the service before compile my changes, and then restarting.